# Merging lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Here I have two lines in QGIS. There is a part when they overlap. I want to merge them so it will be one line in the middle.

[image]
I have tried the solutions already mentioned previously but no success. 
What I tried:

- [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254788/merging-close-lines/255273) to [Merging close lines using v.clean](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254788/merging-close-lines)
- [How to merge lines with slightly different endpoints in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/how-to-merge-lines-with-slightly-different-endpoints-in-qgis)
- [Merging lines (with and with no overlaps) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307936/merging-lines-with-and-with-no-overlaps-in-qgis)
- [Merging overlapping lines into one line. QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271025/merging-overlapping-lines-into-one-line-qgis)
- [Join / merge lines that touch and intersect in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198317/join-merge-lines-that-touch-and-intersect-in-qgis)
- [Merging adjacent lines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228267/merging-adjacent-lines-in-qgis)
- [How to connect two line ends in QGIS without resorting to other software?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98320/how-to-connect-two-line-ends-in-qgis-without-resorting-to-other-software/133391)

This is what I want to get:

[image]

How do I merge them?

Comment: What happens when you use `v.clean` with `snap`?

Comment: @Erik , when I use v.clean with snap I produces a lot of noise.... 
This is what I get https://imgur.com/a/GvXzBzr

Comment: For the overlap part you could try one of my two solutions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123731/create-mean-line-from-multiple-lines-using-qgis/271532#271532

Comment: Your desired tool is available in QGIS 3 as  "Snap geometries to layer" in Processing Tool Box. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your tool is "Snap geometries to layer" (only in QGIS 3) from Processing Tool Box.

For testing purpose, I created two lines similar to your layers; as it can be observed in following image (scale 1:1000):

[image]

Afterward, I launch that tool with parameters of following image (for my scale, adequate tolerance is 8 m):

[image]

After running it, I got:

[image]

whose result was merged as expected (line 1 was unchecked in Map Legend for better visualization).

Comment: the problem I have is that: https://imgur.com/a/qFqBYMT
I want to perform that operation on one layer generalized [17], which have 17 features/lines. 

When I do that, Im getting the red trail.